# Fixing meshes to make them PWN

Tags: graphics, 3d, polygon, computational-geometry, mesh

I intend to use [libigl booleanoperations](https://libigl.github.io/tutorial/#boolean-operations-on-meshes) on my meshes, like this:

```cpp
igl::copyleft::cgal::mesh_boolean(VA, FA, VB, FB, igl::MESH_BOOLEAN_TYPE_MINUS, V, F);
```

As noted [here](https://github.com/libigl/libigl/issues/1691#issuecomment-754407344):

> mesh_boolean assumes the inputs are PWN http://www.cs.columbia.edu/cg/mesh-arrangements/#definitions which includes being oriented so that normals computed using right hand rule point outward

So, I have to make sure my meshes are PWN.

> PWN: A (triangle) mesh inducing a piecewise constant generalized winding number field. These meshes may contain self-intersections, non-manifold elements, multiple components, degenerate faces, and even open boundaries (seams), so long as the winding number is still piecewise constant.

How can I make my meshes PWN?

#### Tried

I tried to fix my meshes by [MeshFix](https://github.com/MarcoAttene/MeshFix-V2.1). But it does much more than just making the meshes PWN. What other tools are available which I might be missing?